# Dynamically updating string from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of divs that contain a string in h3 format. Upon clicking these divs (they are all the same class) a screen is displayed (part of the same html doc) containing some sliders for user input.

Is there a way to make it so that when the screen is displayed it contains the string of whatever div was clicked? In other words, if the user taps/clicks the "Push Ups" card, I would like the div "#info" to update to shoe "push Ups", if the user selects "Iquats" I would like "#info" to show "Squats" ec.

I can't think of a way to do this without using JSON or some sort of server magic. CODE!

HTML:

```
<!--HEADER-->
<div class="header">
  <div id="info">
    <p>Select Exercise</p> <!--THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE STRING TO UPDATE-->
  </div>
</div>

<!--EXERCISE LIST-->
<div id="exerciseContainer">
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Push Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Dips</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Burpees</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Plank</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Sit Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Leg Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Russian Twists</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Back Raises</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<!--SPECIFY TIMING FOR EXERCISES-->
<div id="specifier">
  <div id="containSliders">
    <!--Exercise time allocator-->
    <h1></h1> <!--I WOULD LIKE THIS TO UPDATE ALSO-->
    <div id="containSliderOne">
      <p>Time:</p>
      <output id="timeValue">60 sec.</output>
      <input type="range" id="determineTime" step="10" value="60" min="0" max="180" />
    </div>
    <!--Exercise time allocator-->
    <div id="containSliderTwo">
      <p>Rest Time:</p>
      <output id="restValue">10 sec.</output>
      <input type="range" id="determineRest" step="10" value="10" min="0" max="180" />
    </div>
    <!--Add rest button-->
    <div id="addBreak"><p>Add Break</p></div>
    <!--Back Button-->
    <div id="cancel">
      <a id="exerciseCancel" href="exercises.html">
        <img src="images/backButtonUp.png" width="100" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/backButtonDown.png" width="85" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--Confirm Button-->
    <div id="confirm">
      <a id="exerciseConfirm" href="routineOverview.html">
        <img src="images/whiteTickUp.png" width="95" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/whiteTickDown.png" width="80" alt=""/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
  $(".exercise").click(function()
  {
    $("#specifier").css("display", "block");
    $(".backButton").css("display", "none");
  });
```

Thanks for any help and ideas given!

Comment: you need a tabs plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can get the clicked element text by using $(this).text() inside the click event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.exercise').click(function() {
    $('#info').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--HEADER-->
<div class="header">
  <div id="info">
    <p>Select Exercise</p>
    <!--THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE STRING TO UPDATE-->
  </div>
</div>

<!--EXERCISE LIST-->
<div id="exerciseContainer">
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Push Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Dips</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Burpees</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Plank</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Sit Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Leg Ups</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseL exercise">
    <h3>Russian Twists</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="exerciseR exercise">
    <h3>Back Raises</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<!--SPECIFY TIMING FOR EXERCISES-->
<div id="specifier">
  <div id="containSliders">
    <!--Exercise time allocator-->
    <h1></h1>
    <!--I WOULD LIKE THIS TO UPDATE ALSO-->
    <div id="containSliderOne">
      <p>Time:</p>
      <output id="timeValue">60 sec.</output>
      <input type="range" id="determineTime" step="10" value="60" min="0" max="180" />
    </div>
    <!--Exercise time allocator-->
    <div id="containSliderTwo">
      <p>Rest Time:</p>
      <output id="restValue">10 sec.</output>
      <input type="range" id="determineRest" step="10" value="10" min="0" max="180" />
    </div>
    <!--Add rest button-->
    <div id="addBreak">
      <p>Add Break</p>
    </div>
    <!--Back Button-->
    <div id="cancel">
      <a id="exerciseCancel" href="exercises.html">
        <img src="images/backButtonUp.png" width="100" alt="" />
        <img src="images/backButtonDown.png" width="85" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--Confirm Button-->
    <div id="confirm">
      <a id="exerciseConfirm" href="routineOverview.html">
        <img src="images/whiteTickUp.png" width="95" alt="" />
        <img src="images/whiteTickDown.png" width="80" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to create the elements programatically.

```
var arrExercises = ['Push Ups', 'Dips', 'Burpees'];//add all exercises here
arrExercises.forEach(function(exercise, i){
    var $exercise = $('<div>', {id:'div-excercise-'+i, "class":'exercise'});//create the exercise element
    //give the on click handler to the exercise
    $exercise.on('click', function(e){
        $("#specifier").css("display", "block");
        $(".backButton").css("display", "none");
        $("#info").text(exercise);//set the info to the exercise text
    });
    $('#exerciseContainer').append($exercise);//append this exercise to the container
});
```